# Why does clang/llvm on windows require Visual Studio's Link.exe?

Tags: windows, linker, llvm, clang, llc

According to [LLVM's Getting Started (Windows) site](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html):

> ... Clang can be used to emit bitcode, directly emit object files or even linked executables using Visual Studio’s link.exe.

Why is the use of `Link.exe` on Windows necessary? And, for that matter, what is used on Mac/Linux? Further down it says:

```
Compile the program to object code using the LLC code generator:
    C:\..> llc -filetype=obj hello.bc
Link to binary using Microsoft link:
    C:\..> link hello.obj -defaultlib:libcmt
```

Why can't LLC perform that last step? LLI seems to work fine so I assume that it interoperates with `link.exe` somehow under the hood - why can't LLC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because no one has written a linker for LLVM.

There is a project to do so (called, unimaginatively `lld`) but it's not ready yet.

See http://lld.llvm.org for more details.

On the mac, people use Apple's linker, `ld`.

On Linux, most people use the gnu linker, usually (also) named `ld`

Comment: I guess this means LLVM doesn't do LTO?

Comment: @Mehrdad: LLVM does LTO on IR level. But even if an executable is produced from a single .s file, it still has to be linked.

Comment: @Mehrdad, both `gold` and Mac `ld` can use LLVM plugin for LTO.

Comment: lld is supported on windows in the meantime

Comment: Is this answer still up to date? The default LLVM install still assumes you're using Visual Studio, but is LLD more stable now and seems to be ready as a drop in replacement (assuming with some default config changes)?

Answer (score 5):

Try MinGW-W64's ld. I've been using it with llvm's clang instead of VS tools that I used for building clang in the first place.